# Bing Maps How to zoom into the mouse cursor location?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I am working on WinRT and using bing maps.
I saw it is possible to zoom into the mouse cursor location.
All implementations I saw was in JavaScript but I need it in C#.
How to do that?

Comment: Does mouse wheel not zoom the map ?

Comment: It does but not to the mouse cursor location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't pay attention but the default behavior of the zoom is to zoom to the mouse direction !

So no need to implement it !